# Easylist failure with utf8 characters

Tags: listingsutf8

When trying to compile the following example document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}
& Förklara, diskutera och analysera trådlösa protokoll och nätvärkstyper.
& Förklara, diskutera och analysera prestandaproblem så som:
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

```
pdflatex BG-1.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)

entering extended mode
(./BG-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, farsi, arabic, croatian, bulgarian, ukrainian, russian, czech, slov
ak, danish, dutch, finnish, french, basque, ngerman, german, german-x-2009-06-1
9, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, ibycus, monogreek, greek, ancientgreek, hungarian, san
skrit, italian, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian2a, mongolian, bokmal, nyn
orsk, romanian, irish, coptic, serbian, turkish, welsh, esperanto, uppersorbian
, estonian, indonesian, interlingua, icelandic, kurmanji, slovenian, polish, po
rtuguese, spanish, galician, catalan, swedish, ukenglish, pinyin, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/var/lib/texmf/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/swedish.ldf
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/easylist/easylist.sty) (./BG-1.aux)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@a 
l.11 & Förklara, diskutera och analysera trå
                                              dlösa protokoll och nätvärk...
```

Seems like it tries to interpret 'å' as a number. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: easylist redefines `\r` to mean `\roman` (\def\r{\roman}). That's a very bad idea. (It also redefines \l which is also a LICR command). Report the bug to the author.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This fix won't work as the redefinition is done in `\el@PrintCounters` which is called at the ampersand. So `\let\r\oldr` is needed after each `&`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer odd: I claim to have tested that yesterday (which is how I noticed `[swedish]` doesn't work) but you are correct the `\r` fix doesn't work either. I'll delete the comment, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was provided by the author of the plugin Paul Isambert. As he writes:

> Ulrike is right: redefing \r and others was pretty stupid (I was still a TeX
>   novice when I wrote easylist). Attached is a corrected version of easylist.sty
>   (untested, I have no LaTeX here at work), just drop it where it should go. I
>   don't know if that's where your bug comes from, but that is a bug anyway. I'm
>   not sure I'll be upgrading the package soon (it's more or less unmaintained),
>   so do not lose that version :)

He provided an updated version of the extension which I uploaded to a [pastebin](https://gist.github.com/Rovanion/6583499). Replacing my system version of the file, which was located in `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/easylist/easylist.sty` on Debian/Ubuntu, with this updated version solves the problem.

Comment: Paul emailed me today to say that he had updated the package on CTAN meaning that distribution packages made after 2014-01-11 should contain the fix.